# Tensorflow 2.0 dataset batching not working properly

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

Tensorflow 2.0 dataset api's batch is not working as I expected it to work.

I've made a dataset like this.

```
self.train_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(generator=train_generator, output_types=(tf.float32, tf.float32), output_shapes=(tf.TensorShape([6]), tf.TensorShape([])))
```

This yields DatasetV1Adapter shapes: ((6,), ()), types: (tf.float32, tf.float32),
and to this dataset I applied batch function from tf.data.Dataset.

```
self.train_dataset.batch(1024)
```

yields DatasetV1Adapter shapes: ((None, 6), (None,)), types: (tf.float32, tf.float32), and changing the batch size doesn't help at all.

From official description of the batch,

> The components of the resulting element will have an additional outer dimension, which will be batch_size (or N % batch_size for the last element if batch_size does not divide the number of input elements N evenly and drop_remainder is False). If your program depends on the batches having the same outer dimension, you should set the drop_remainder argument to True to prevent the smaller batch from being produced.

The way I thought this function would work, was to make [batch, 6], [batch,] but didn't work out well.

I originally used pytorch, and started using TF 2.0 recently, and need some help on proper batching. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the desired result by setting,

```
train_dataset = train_dataset.batch(2, drop_remainder=True)
```

`drop_remainder=False` by default. When that's the case, the first dimension **must** be `None` as there will (most probably) be a batch with `< batch_size` elements at the end of the dataset, because the number of samples is not divisible by `batch_size`.